# Create Table of Content using Values in Table

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Microsoft Word - VBA, is it possible to create a VBA macro to read from a table and then create a table of content ?

I have tried macro to create Table of Content based on Heading and Subheading and no issue with that. However, I can't get the right when I loop through the table.

Example in my Table

> Row 1 - Cell_1, Cell_2, Cell_3
>   Row 2 - Cell_1, Cell_2, Cell_3
>   Row 3 - Cell_1, Cell_2, Cell_3

I would like to take the text from Cell_2 and create a table of content.

Can I utilize the Add Method as decribed here ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835785.aspx

Any example that you can share ? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible and it's not possible. **Is Possible**- yes, you could take cell value and put it as separate paragraph + give number before + find appropriate section in your document to give number of the page. But it doesn't have any sense- it will never be dynamic and page numbers will be not automatically updated. So, **it's not possible**. Creating table of content using Heading and Subheading it's relatively easy. You need to practice a bit more and finally you get it.

Comment: I have seen an "Add In" that able to do what I described but I am not able to figure out how they do it. The page number generated are dynamic. The problem I have is, there are 2 TOC. 1 TOC is heading and sub heading and another TOC should be based on the value in the table cells.

I have no problem creating the TOC using Heading and Subheading. Just record the macro and make some tweaks to the range. The challenge is the cell section.

Have you tried Mark Entry before ? Thanks

Comment: if there is any 'add in' just install it and do the job. I don't know Mark Entry, possibly because I've never needed anything extra to do TOC.

Comment: Are you creating a new document based on the table? Or does the table refer to headings already in the document?

Comment: You either use specific paragraph styles in your table that allow you to build the ToC using the \c switch in the TOC field, or copy each cell's content into a TC field and use those to build your TOC, or build it more directly as KazJaw suggested. If you are having trouble retrieving the existing cell txt, you should (a) have a look around for code that accesses table cells and then consider modifying your question by providing some code.

Comment: @KazJaw - seen that before but forgotten the name of the tool.

Comment: @Christina - no I just want to append the TOC to the end of the document. There's a TOC based on heading1 or sub heading in the first few pages of the document. This table is something extra like appendix.

Comment: @bibadia - I found another way which is to use Bookmark. Then build TOC using Bookmark. Do you think possible to code ?

Comment: reading your comments I doubt if you have asked precise question and if we all get you right. Think of question elaboration by adding some more information, pictures, etc. Using bookmarks sound good but remember- it won't be auto updated- you will need to run macros. Think of `Fields` instead `Bookmarks` which could are easier to update.

Comment: @user3015739 I agree with KazJaw. Further, in the ToC field (if that is what you are using), the bookmark option is only there to let you specify which part of the document you want to generate ToC entries for.